# something weird happens after I run vi in my command line

Tags: linux, bash, vi

Something like below appears and will never stop after I run `vi` in my command line.

Name collision between I9 I9 I9 I9 I9 I9 I9 I9 I9 I9 I9 I9 I9 I9 I9 I9 I9

Name collision between Ia Ia Ia Ia Ia Ia Ia Ia Ia Ia Ia Ia Ia Ia Ia Ia Ia

Comment: Did you change your .vimrc recently?

Comment: I can not find the file .vimrc now.  $ls -a|grep vi                            
.vim
.viminfo

Comment: May be this can help - http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23360/why-am-i-getting-name-collision-between-errors-and-how-can-i-fix-them

Comment: simply delete vi and install it again :D

Answer (score 0):

try starting vim without using any plug-ins or customizations. You could do that by typing 
vim -u NONE and also if you don't know where your .vimrc is you should look into the find command in Linux. once you use the "find" command and you are unsuccessful. create a new .vimrc. the home directory would be a good location.After you have created a new .vimrc source that .vimrc and it should fix that problem. if you are not sure what I mean by source. An example would be "source $HOME/tom/.vimrc"